# Xlcalculator example throws a TypeError asking for a rich_text positional argument. What do I set the positional argument to?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

I am running the xlcalculator example, code below.

```
import logging
from xlcalculator import ModelCompiler
from xlcalculator import Model
from xlcalculator import Evaluator

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

json_file_name = r'use_case_01.json'

filename = r'use_case_01.xlsm'
compiler = ModelCompiler()
new_model = compiler.read_and_parse_archive(filename, build_code=False)
new_model.persist_to_json_file(json_file_name)

reconstituted_model = Model()
reconstituted_model.construct_from_json_file(json_file_name, build_code=True)

evaluator = Evaluator(reconstituted_model)
val1 = evaluator.evaluate('First!A2')
print("value 'evaluated' for First!A2 without a formula:", val1)
val2 = evaluator.evaluate('Seventh!C1')
print("value 'evaluated' for Seventh!C1 with a formula:", val2)
val3 = evaluator.evaluate('Ninth!B1')
print("value 'evaluated' for Ninth!B1 with a defined name:", val3)
val4 = evaluator.evaluate('Hundred')
print("value 'evaluated' for Hundred with a defined name:", val4)
val5 = evaluator.evaluate('Tenth!C1')
print("value 'evaluated' for Tenth!C1 with a defined name:", val5)
val6 = evaluator.evaluate('Tenth!C2')
print("value 'evaluated' for Tenth!C2 with a defined name:", val6)
val7 = evaluator.evaluate('Tenth!C3')
print("value 'evaluated' for Tenth!C3 with a defined name:", val7)

evaluator.set_cell_value('First!A2', 88)
val17 = evaluator.evaluate('First!A2')
print("New value for First!A2 is", val17)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 8
      6 filename = 'Inputs/BBC MAT TEMPLATE (updated 9.11.23)-From Jake.xlsx'
      7 compiler = ModelCompiler()
----> 8 new_model = compiler.read_and_parse_archive(filename, build_code=False)
      9 new_model.persist_to_json_file(json_file_name)
     11 reconstituted_model = Model()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xlcalculator/model.py:183, in ModelCompiler.read_and_parse_archive(self, file_name, ignore_sheets, ignore_hidden, build_code)
    179 def read_and_parse_archive(
    180         self, file_name=None, ignore_sheets=[], ignore_hidden=False,
    181         build_code=True
    182 ):
--> 183     archive = self.read_excel_file(file_name)
    184     self.parse_archive(
    185         archive, ignore_sheets=ignore_sheets, ignore_hidden=ignore_hidden)
    187     if build_code:

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xlcalculator/model.py:167, in ModelCompiler.read_excel_file(self, file_name)
    165 def read_excel_file(self, file_name):
    166     archive = reader.Reader(file_name)
--> 167     archive.read()
    168     return archive

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xlcalculator/reader.py:13, in Reader.read(self)
     11 def read(self):
     12     with patch.openpyxl_WorksheetReader_patch():
---> 13         self.book = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.excel_file_name)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py:317, in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    290 """Open the given filename and return the workbook
    291 
    292 :param filename: the path to open or a file-like object
   (...)
    313 
    314 """
    315 reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
    316                     data_only, keep_links)
--> 317 reader.read()
    318 return reader.wb

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py:282, in ExcelReader.read(self)
    280 self.read_theme()
    281 apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
--> 282 self.read_worksheets()
    283 self.parser.assign_names()
    284 if not self.read_only:

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py:227, in ExcelReader.read_worksheets(self)
    225     ws = self.wb.create_sheet(sheet.name)
    226     ws._rels = rels
--> 227     ws_parser = WorksheetReader(ws, fh, self.shared_strings, self.data_only)
    228     ws_parser.bind_all()
    230 # assign any comments to cells

TypeError: WorksheetReader.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rich_text'
```

I see that xlcalculator is based on a few libraries, one of which is openpyxl. I suspect there are dependency issues at play, but I am not sure what to do. I naively tried setting rich_text = True. However, that did not work.

Does anyone know how to resolve this TypeError?

xlcalculator can be found here: https://github.com/bradbase/xlcalculator/tree/master.

I am ultimately trying to use excel functions in a python script. If someone had better ideas than using xlcalculator, I am open to them!

Thank you for reading this and if you respond, an extra thanks!

Comment: Please include the relevant code as text and not as a link to your code.

Comment: @ewokx, I spaced on providing the relevant code and full error message. I updated the question to include them. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: What version of openpyxl do you have?

Comment: @ewokx, my openpyxl version is 3.0.10

Comment: @ewokx ...I updated openpyxl and this seems to work now. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by updating my openpyxl with "pip install openpyxl -U". Thank you @ewokx for guiding me to this solution!